# Unable to create kafka topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to create a kafka topic on ec2 instance, 
i am following this documentation https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/real-time-stream-processing-using-apache-spark-streaming-and-apache-kafka-on-aws/
but i am getting the following error please help

```
ec2-user@ip-10-100-53-218 bin]$ ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
Error while executing topic command : replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
[2017-03-20 12:25:30,045] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: replication factor: 1 larger than available brokers: 0
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

Answer (score 0):

The kafka broker is not running. SSH into the Kafka Broker instance and check if kafka-server-start.sh is running.

```
ps -ef | grep kafka-server-start
```

If not running, start it.

```
nohup /app/kafka/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /app/kafka/kafka_2.9.2-0.8.2.1/config/server.properties
```

Comment: its running, but still the same error
[ec2-user@ip-10-100-52-58 config]$ ps -ef | grep kafka-server-start
ec2-user 30375 27676  0 13:52 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto kafka-server-start

Comment: Can you post the whole output of ps -ef. There should be 2 lines coming as output. The 1 line you have given is for the grep you have run.